# Antlr4 Project Directory Structure Issue

Tags: java, antlr4, javac

I'm trying to set up an Antlr4 project using Java's package directory structure.

The top level directory contains `PondParser.g4`, `PondLexer.g4`, and `build_script`.

`build_script` is expected to build and run the antlr4 test rig

```
{ 
    echo 'clean project' 
    find ./com/sevan/pond/ -type f -delete
} && { 
    echo 'launch ANTLR parser generator' 
    java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.8-complete.jar -package com.sevan.pond  ./PondLexer.g4 -o com/sevan/pond
    java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.8-complete.jar -package com.sevan.pond  ./PondParser.g4 -o com/sevan/pond
} && { 
    echo 'compile .java files'
    javac ./com/sevan/pond/*.java 
} && {
    echo 'run test rig with gui'
    java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig  ./com/sevan/pond/PondParser prog -gui 
}
```

Relevant `PondParser.g4` header and options:

```
parser grammar PondParser;

@header {   
    package com.sevan.pond;
}

options {
    tokenVocab = PondLexer;
}
```

Relevant `PondLexer.g4` header and options:

```
lexer grammar PondLexer ;

@header {   
    package com.sevan.pond;
}
```

The build script fails while compiling (`javac ./com/sevan/pond/*.java` ).

The specific errors are as follows:

```
./com/sevan/pond/LexerRules.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    package com.sevan.pond;
    ^
./com/sevan/pond/Pond.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    package com.sevan.pond;
    ^
./com/sevan/pond/PondBaseListener.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    package com.sevan.pond;
    ^
./com/sevan/pond/PondListener.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    package com.sevan.pond;
    ^
4 errors
```

What's missing/wrong here? Any suggestions, links, and answers would be greatly appreciated.

---

### Update

The four errors above were due to a double package declaration in the generated java files.  This was caused by specifying the package using `-package` and `@header`.  After fixing this, however, the test rig still fails with `Can't load PondParser as lexer or parser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
# *nix
javac -cp .:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.8-complete.jar ./com/sevan/pond/*.java 

# Windows
javac -cp .;path\to\antlr-4.8-complete.jar .\com\sevan\pond\*.java
```

?

I.e.: you want to add the current working dir to the classpath (`.`), as well as the ANTLR lib.

### EDIT

Here's a working demo (just tested it myself).

Files/folder structure:

```
-+
 |
 +-- antlr-4.8-complete.jar
 |
 +-- com/
      |
      +-- sevan/
           |
           +-- pond/
                |
                +-- PondParser.g4
                |
                +-- PondLexer.g4
```

Navigate to where `antlr-4.8-complete.jar` resides.

Generate lexer and parser classes:

```
java -jar antlr-4.8-complete.jar -package com.sevan.pond com/sevan/pond/*.g4
```

And compile all generated `.java` files:

```
javac -cp .:antlr-4.8-complete.jar com/sevan/pond/*.java
```

Fianlly, run TestRig as follows:

```
java -cp .:antlr-4.8-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig com.sevan.pond.Pond prog -gui
```

You can now enter some text and can terminate by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. I typed `abc\n` and got this:

[image]

For reference, heres what the grammars look like:

#### PondLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar PondLexer;

ANY
 : .
 ;
```

#### PondParser.g4

```
parser grammar PondParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=PondLexer;
}

prog
 : ANY* EOF
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Bart.  Appending the current working dir isn't affecting the build.  After fixing the double package declaration (see updated question), the errors went away. Now I'm getting `Can't load PondParser as lexer or parser`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I really appreciate the working example.  It was a combination of the classpath and the location of the `.g4` files.

Comment: You're welcome @SevanGolnazarian. Yeah, `TestRig` produces some odd messages when the lexer- and parser classes cannot be found on the CLASSPATH. Also tricky is the fact that the grammar name should be provided without the `Parser` part. Anyway, good to hear you got things working.